# Can't reach localhost on vagrant

Tags: wordpress, localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

On my Macbook I'm using VirtualBox+Vagrant. For Vagrant I downloaded VagrantPress (from vagrantpress.org), which is a Vagrantfile with Wordpress and some Puppet scripts. It looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "base"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080

config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "init.pp"
    puppet.options="--verbose --debug"
  end
end
```

At first, this was running as intended (viewing the Wordpress installation on localhost), but I have it installed on a Dropbox sub-directory, and while trying to get it to work on another computer which runs Ubuntu, I may have changed something that broke the whole setup.

Now, when running 'Vagrant up' on my macbook (which used to run well), I see this:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] -- 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
GuestAdditions versions on your host (4.2.18) and guest (4.1.12) do not match.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
dkms is already the newest version.
dkms set to manually installed.
linux-headers-3.2.0-54-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.2.0-54-generic set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Copy iso file /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
mount: warning: /mnt seems to be mounted read-only.
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 4.2.18 - guest version is 4.1.12
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 4.2.18 Guest Additions for Linux............
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
You appear to have a version of the VBoxGuestAdditions software
on your system which was installed from a different source or using a
different type of installer.  If you installed it from a package from your
Linux distribution or if it is a default part of the system then we strongly
recommend that you cancel this installation and remove it properly before
installing this version.  If this is simply an older or a damaged
installation you may safely proceed.

Do you wish to continue anyway? [yes or no]

Cancelling installation.
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 4.2.18. Some         functionality may not work as intended.
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
cause things such as shared folders to not work properly. If you see
shared folder errors, please update the guest additions within the
virtual machine and reload your VM.

Guest Additions Version: 4.1.12
VirtualBox Version: 4.2
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0
```

and localhost on Chrome says 'No data received'. 
After that, I 'Vagrant ssh' and ran:

```
curl 'http://localhost/'
```

and get:

```
cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host ...
```

I have been trying to fix this for days now. I even tried reinstalling Vagrant and VirtualBox but it didn't work.
Also, I tried to manually update the Guest Additions (although this was not necessary before), and after getting 'GuestAdditions 4.2.18 running --- OK.' after booting the VM, I still get the same errors for localhost.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, you would want to try `http://localhost:8080/` on the host system (in order to connect with port 80 on the guest).

Inside the guest OS, are you sure the webserver is running? It might not be starting automatically.

Also, I think you can ignore the Guest Additions version mismatch. It's likely not related to the problem you're seeing.